# Remove colon from all the observarions

Tags: sas

I have a variable and more of them has a colon (:) in the sentence. Like 
AC: acuimule, AB: abitre,..

I need to remove colons from all rows in that variable. I tried

```
proc sql;
create table aaa as
 select variable1,
 variable2=compress(variable2,":")
 FROM aaa2
;QUIT;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use PROC SQL, you don't use =.

```
proc sql;
create table aaa as
 select variable1,
 compress(variable2,':') as variable2
 FROM aaa2
;
quit;
```